# swift: Increase TableViewCell Height depend on UILabel without using Constraints

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, height

I want to increase my UITableviewCell height depends on UILabel content on TableViewCell button click.
I have search on it, but I find answers on constraints.

I want to increase UITabelViewCell height dynamically without using 'Constarints'/Autolayout.

I have get Label Height using below code:

```
func getLabelHeight(lbl : UILabel) -> CGFloat
    {
        let constraint = CGSizeMake(lbl.frame.size.width, CGFloat.max)
        var size = CGSize()

        let context = NSStringDrawingContext();

        let boundingBox : CGSize

        boundingBox = NSString(string: lbl.text!).boundingRectWithSize(constraint,
                                                                    options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                                    attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self],
                                                                    context: context).size

        size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height))
        return size.height;
    }
```

but I can't use this code in UITableview. To increase TableViewCell height I have written the below code:

```
func btnReadMoreClick(sender: UIButton){
        let buttonTag = sender.tag

        indexOfReadMoreButton = sender.tag
        isReadMoreButtonTouched = true

        tableVDetail.beginUpdates()
        tableVDetail.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: indexOfReadMoreButton, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        tableVDetail.endUpdates()
    }
```

and set cell Height in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

But using this I can't get my outPut. :(

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: if you really want go this way, make this function to calculate height static and pass directly into text to bound, so you can in easy way call CellName.getLabelHeight... at heightForRowAtIndex....

Comment: @mbutan can you plz explain me using code. or if you have another way then plz tell that way also.

Answer (score 0):

If you set properly constraints on your cell, it should do the rest of the work.

It's a helper which automatically resize your cell and will calculate expecting height.

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func calcualteHeight(inTableview tableview: UITableView) -> CGFloat {
        self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        let height = self.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(self.bounds.size, withHorizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel).height
        return height
    }
}
```

In TableView delegate, fetch your calculating cell and fill data.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.viewModel.reuseIdentifier(atIndexPath: indexPath)) as! YourCell
       cell.setupData(fillCellYourData)
       return cell.calcualteHeight(inTableview: tableView)
}
```

Comment: I wnt this without using constraints on cell